# Performance problems with a non-trivial view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried a long time to create a working view, and it was not possible without asking for help. But now, the view exists and is created with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users2 AS (

SELECT DISTINCT p.username
    , p.password
    , p.firstName
    , p.lastName
    , eMail AS email
    , a.settlement AS city
    , s.name AS country
    , pl.languages
    , p.description
    , p.ID AS ID
    , p.phone1
    , p.phone2
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', a.street, a.addition) AS address
    , p.status
    , p.publicMail
    , p.advisorID
    , (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', (SELECT t.title
                                    FROM titles AS t
                                    WHERE p1.titleID = t.ID), p1.firstName, p1.lastName) AS name
        FROM persons p1, titles t
        WHERE (p1.titleID IS NULL OR p1.titleID = t.ID)
          AND p1.ID = p.advisorID) AS Betreuer
FROM addresses a, addresses_have_persons ap, countries c, persons p, states s
    , persons_language AS pl
WHERE a.ID = addressID
  AND a.Countries_ID = c.ID
  AND a.States_ID = s.ID
  AND ap.Addresses_ID = a.ID
  AND ap.Persons_ID = p.ID
  AND p.ID = pl.ID);
```

It should replace a similar table called 'users'. To display the 'users' table on my local MySQL takes at most two seconds, and 19 records are displayed. To open the 'users2' view with the same amount of records to display, but with about 150 records in the main table 'persons', takes about 15 seconds.

I see here a performance issue. Do you have an idea how to improve this SELECT that creates the view 'users2'?

I checked the subselect

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', (SELECT t.title
                                    FROM titles AS t
                                    WHERE p1.titleID = t.ID), p1.firstName, p1.lastName) AS name
    FROM persons p1, titles t
    WHERE (p1.titleID IS NULL OR p1.titleID = t.ID)
      AND p1.ID = p.advisorID
```

It responds within a second. Accessing the view *persons_language* takes about three seconds.

Thank you in advance!

The EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY ap  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    19      
1   PRIMARY p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test_apptest.ap.Persons_ID  1   Using where
1   PRIMARY a   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) 
1   PRIMARY s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test_apptest.a.States_ID    1   
1   PRIMARY c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test_apptest.a.Countries_ID 1   Using index 
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ref key0    key0    5   test_apptest.ap.Persons_ID  10
1   PRIMARY padvisor    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    146 Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) 
1   PRIMARY t   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test_apptest.padvisor.titleID   1   Using where 
3   DERIVED lp  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    296 Using filesort  
3   DERIVED l   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test_apptest.lp.Languages_ID    1
```

Comment: While the subselect corresponds within a second when tested in isolation, in your actual query/view it being run a correlated subquery, which can be a big performance killer.  On top of this, you may not have indices setup on the join columns or columns in the `WHERE` clause.  A view will only perform as well as the underlying SQL.  So, refactor to get rid of the correlated subquery, and then run `EXPLAIN` to see how an index might help.

Comment: But the creating SELECT answers within a couple of seconds. Strange… very strange!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.   *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why not?

Comment: addressID and ap.Addresses_ID must be the same value? The address joining looks strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT p.username
    , p.password
    , p.firstName
    , p.lastName
    , p.eMail AS email
    , a.settlement AS city
    , s.name AS country
    , pl.languages
    , p.description
    , p.ID AS ID
    , p.phone1
    , p.phone2
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', a.street, a.addition) AS address
    , p.status
    , p.publicMail
    , p.advisorID
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', t.title, padvisor.firstName, padvisor.lastName) AS Betreuer
FROM addresses a, addresses_have_persons ap, countries c, persons p, states s
    , persons_language AS pl
LEFT JOIN persons padvisor ON padvisor.ID = p.advisorID
LEFT JOIN titles t ON t.ID = padvisor.titleID 
WHERE a.ID = p.addressID
  AND a.Countries_ID = c.ID
  AND a.States_ID = s.ID
  AND ap.Addresses_ID = a.ID
  AND ap.Persons_ID = p.ID
  AND p.ID = pl.ID;
```

Please note that

- when your schema is properly normalised, you shouldn't need DISTINCT.
- the join syntax introduced in the ANSI SQL Standard '92 is much more readable. Feel free to convert your query entirely to the JOIN syntax.

For the next step we need the result of `EXPLAIN <your_query>;` and the create statements of your tables so we know about your indexes and so on.

**EDIT:**
Here is the same query in "modern" syntax (something 25 years old cannot be really modern, but the syntax I used was still older):

```
SELECT p.username
    , p.password
    , p.firstName
    , p.lastName
    , p.eMail AS email
    , a.settlement AS city
    , s.name AS country
    , pl.languages
    , p.description
    , p.ID AS ID
    , p.phone1
    , p.phone2
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', a.street, a.addition) AS address
    , p.status
    , p.publicMail
    , CONCAT_WS(' ', t.title, p2.firstName, p2.lastName) AS Betreuer
FROM addresses a
    INNER JOIN addresses_have_persons ap ON a.ID = ap.Addresses_ID
    INNER JOIN countries c ON a.Countries_ID = c.ID
    INNER JOIN persons p ON a.ID = p.addressID
        AND ap.Persons_ID = p.ID
    INNER JOIN states s ON a.States_ID = s.ID
    INNER JOIN persons_language pl ON p.ID = pl.ID
LEFT JOIN persons p2 ON p2.ID = p2.advisorID
LEFT JOIN titles t ON t.ID = p2.titleID;
```

Comment: Hmm, this query should result in a syntax error because `left join` has higher precedence than the comma operator. Therefore `persons_language AS pl LEFT JOIN persons padvisor ON padvisor.ID = p.advisorID` join is executed first. However, when this join is executed, the `p` alias is not defined yet.

Comment: As I'm always using the JOIN syntax the whole way through I'm not familiar with this. Consider this answer as an example how to write it. I was to lazy to rewrite the whole comma separated bulk, therefore my suggestion that OP does it as sort of a "homework".

Comment: Interestingly, the server "understands" the code & does the right thing. 8-s

Comment: @Sae1962 First things first. In the third column you see the alias of the table. When in the fourth column is an "ALL" this means it does a full table scan. That's almost the worst that can happen. Look for the columns of that table that are used for joining (in your case linking in the where clause) and have an index on both the column used for join as well as the referenced column. When the primary key or another index is used (column key after possible _keys), you don't need to add another index.

Comment: I'll have to leave now. Going to continue tomorrow. Thank you for your help, @fancyPants, thank you, @Shadow! :-)

Comment: @Sae1962 just tried it out and you should get `#1054 - Unknown column 'p.advisorID' in 'on clause'` error message if you run the suggested query.

Comment: The newly added query in "modern" syntax runs without problems. Obviously, I somehow corrected the error.

Comment: @Sae1962 Please edit additional info into the question, not answers. Also keep in mind, that MySQL might do a full table scan when you have too few rows in the table, cause then it's actually cheaper to skip the index.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will close this question now.